# How to rewrite the dynamic URL to a short URL by PHP .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite `http://example.com/?paginate=2` as `http://example.com/page/2`.

So I use the following rule to do that, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/([0-9]+) ?paginate=$1 [L]
```

Any suggestions would be great and thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/([0-9]+) ?paginate=$1 [L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* doesn't match your request URL (`/page/2`). You have too many path segments (it would match a URL of the form `/page/something/2`). Instead, you would need a rule like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ ?paginate=$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE:** However, since this is an internal rewrite, you should probably be rewriting directly to the file that is handling the request (probably `index.php` - the `DirectoryIndex`), rather than letting mod_dir do this. By itself, `?paginate=<number>` isn't strictly valid, so mod_dir issues an internal subrequest to `index.php?paginate=<number>`. Ideally, you should be explicit and include the complete URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* to avoid this additional dependency. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?paginate=$1 [L]
```